# Youtube API - how can I exclude unlisted videos?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using google api client to call YouTube Data and YouTube Analytics APIs and get video stats. I'm authenticated as the owner of the channel I am querying.

I am interested in only getting the public videos uploaded in the channel. I first query the YouTube Data API to get the list of videos in the `uploads` playlist and once I have the list of `video ids` I call the youtube Analytics API for each video and get the stats I need.

The problem I'm having is that when I list all videos in the `uploads` playlist I get hundreds of thousands (!!!) of `unlisted` videos, which I don't need.

I cannot afford to download the entire list and then check status to keep only the public videos as the number is too big and I am reaching my daily quota. It would also be a very inefficient way to do it.

is there a way to list only videos with status `public` for a specific playlist?

This is the current method I use:

```
data = service.playlistItems().list(
    part="snippet,status",
    playlistId=playlistID,
    maxResults="50",
).execute()
```

I couldn't find any in the youtube API documentation on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint by not being authenticated, but, instead, using only your [API key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#calling-the-api)  parameter?

I'm assuming here -- though cannot check it myself -- that when not authenticated, the endpoint response will contain only videos that are [public](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you clarify what do you mean by `your API key` parameter?

Comment: As you suggested I used credentials from a different account and got only the public videos. I am a bit surprised that there isn't a better way to filter videos based on status, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Giacomo: The [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#calling-the-api) says: ```In addition, some API methods for retrieving resources may support parameters that require authorization or may contain additional metadata when requests are authorized. For example, a request to retrieve a user's uploaded videos may also contain private videos if the request is authorized by that specific user.``` My suggestion was to use an API key that corresponds to an application which is part of the account that you authenticated yourself against in the first place via OAuth.

Comment: @Giacomo: I cannot test myself the things that I recommend because I have no Youtube account such as yours is (yet am using regularly the API).

Answer (score 0):

As per [the doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#calling-the-api), there are two ways an user can access any given API endpoint: using an API key or, otherwise, by way of an OAuth token.

Any user may request from Google developer's [console](https://console.developers.google.com/) an [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) that he will pass to his endpoint of interest as the [key parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters#key). In case of using the [Python API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/youtube/v3), your code will have to be similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#build):

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build(serviceName = 'youtube', version = 'v3', developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)
```

where [*DEVELOPER_KEY*](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) is the API key string obtained from Google. Please note that such an API key is an user's private information.

That's it: instead of OAuth, use an API key.

Answer (score -1):

This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) text delineates clearly the API's concepts of *authentication* and *authorization*.

Basically, I was assuming that when using an API key instead of being authenticated via OAuth -- that is when [`build`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) receives the parameter `developerKey` instead of `credentials` -- then the endpoint's response will include only *public* videos, even in the case when the respective API key (passed on as parameter `developerKey`) originates from your initial authentication account.